# Command executed with Paramiko does not produce any output

Tags: python, ssh, stdout, paramiko

When I try to do

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('glass-version')
print stdout.readlines()
```

I am getting an empty output.

---

An expected output is:

```
===================== GLASS version details =====================
 GLASS version : 1.2.3
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get no output on `stdout`, it is usually because the command fails to start.

Read `stderr` to check for any errors.

```
print(stderr.readlines())
```

---

Quite often the error is *"<command> not found"*. For that see
[Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848)

---

If you are connecting to a *device*, see also [Executing command using Paramiko exec_command on device is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30603219/850848).