# How to run tmsh(F5) command using python SSH Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, f5, tmsh

How can I run tmsh (f5) command and get output using SSH python ?

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect('1.1.1.1', username='username', password='password')
    ssh.exec_command('ls')    //Working 
    # how to execute tmsh command using ssh ? 
    ssh.exec_command('tmsh show /sys CPU') // ???
```

Comment: So what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: If we use ssh.exec_command('tmsh show /sys CPU') it will provide blank output.

Comment: Start here: [Command executed with Paramiko does not produce any output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066517/850848).

Comment: There was not stderr and stdout.read()  was blank, if i am using this command. I got the solution by changing the command and adding grep to it, please check below.

Answer (score 0):

While working on this I got the solution to solve this problem:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr =  ssh.exec_command("tmsh show /sys CPU | cat")

print stdout.read()
```

Using this command, I can get the tmsh output. Without grep it will return blank output in stdout.read().

Comment: Not sure how this help. But if it really helps, then using `cat` instead of `grep ''` would be a more straightforward solution.