# Python-Paramiko: Connected to server with SSH, not getting output from 'ls' command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ls, ifconfig

I made a client server program using Paramiko. I manage to get a connection, and send command.
For example if I send a 'ifconfig' command, it indeed returns the desired output. Yet, when I try to send an 'ls' command, it returns nothing. I need the server to let me use more complicated commands, like opening files, editing wordpress and so on.

This sends the sshCommand:

```
def sshCommand(command, port=22):
    sshClient = paramiko.SSHClient()  # create SSHClient instance

    sshClient.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())  # AutoAddPolicy automatically adding the hostname and new host key
    sshClient.load_system_host_keys()
    sshClient.connect(host, port, username, password)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = sshClient.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read())
```

When I send -

```
sshCommand('ifconfig')
```

Everything works.
But, sending -

```
sshCommand('ls')
```

Could it be that for some reason I don't have permission to access the files? I also have the root password which is used to connect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug why the command does not work, read also the `stderr`.

See [Command executed with Paramiko does not produce any output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066517/850848).

---

Though if you are going to manipulate files, do not use shell commands. Use SFTP.

See [How to list all the folders and files in the directory after connecting through SFTP in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12295551/850848#57694519).