# Python script stdout is empty while trying to recover logs from remote device

Tags: python, linux, ssh, subprocess, paramiko

I'm trying to recover logs from a remote LB, the script should:

Connect to the LB -> Execute a command -> Check if the stdout is not none -> If it is, update a web page with ALL_GOO -> If there are persistent sessions it should update the web page with NOT_GOOD and send an email with the script output as attachment -> It should then update the file statusEmail with the date of the sent email (this to avoid sending multiple email per day).

When I execute the script I have an empty return: []

```
% ./lb-logs.py  
SSH connection established successfully.
[]
Command executed.
```

This is the main script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import os
from src.utils import run_command, get_results
from datetime import datetime

lbUser = "lb_user"
lbIp = "lb_ip"
lbPass = "lb_pass"
attachment = "p-sessions.txt"
date = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
mailList = "mail_list"

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="logs.log",
    encoding="utf-8",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s",
)

result = get_results(lbIp, lbUser, lbPass)

status = 'UNKNOWN'

if result:
    run_command(
        "sudo sed -i 's/^<h1>.*/<h1>NOT_GOOD-TEST<\/h1>/' /var/www/html/index1.html"
    )
    status = "NOT_GOOD"
    logging.info(f"Status: {status}")
else:
    run_command(
        "sudo sed -i 's/^<h1>.*/<h1>ALL_GOOD-TEST<\/h1>/' /var/www/html/index1.html"
    )
    status = "ALL_GOOD"
    logging.info(f"Status: {status}")

if status == "NOT_GOOD":
    if os.path.exists(attachment):
        logging.info(f"File {attachment} exists.")
        print("File exists.")
    else:
        # Send email if date in statusEmail is different from today's date
        with open("src/statusEmail", "r") as statusEmailFileHandle:
            if date == statusEmailFileHandle.read():
                logging.info("Email already sent.")
            else:
                # Create file
                for line in result:
                    print(line)
                    with open(attachment, "a") as attachmentFileHandle:
                        attachmentFileHandle.write(line + "\n")
                logging.info(f"File {attachment} created.")

                result1 = run_command(
                    f"echo 'Generated from vm: ' | mailx -r 'vm' 'mail_relay' -s 'Persistent sessions found on LB - {date}' -t {mailList} -A {attachment}"
                )

                print(result1)

                with open("src/statusEmail", "w") as f:
                    f.write(f"NOT_GOOD: {date}")
                logging.info("Email sent.")
```

And this is the utils.py:

```
import paramiko
import subprocess
import logging


def connect(lb_ip, lb_user, lb_passwd):
    try:
        _ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        _ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        _ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        _ssh.connect(hostname=lb_ip, username=lb_user, password=lb_passwd)
        return _ssh
        print(_ssh)
    except Exception as exceptHandler:
        logging.error(f"Failed to connect to {ip}: {exceptHandler}")
        raise


def run_command(command):
    _process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    _output, _error = _process.communicate()
    print(_output.decode())
    return _output.decode().strip()


def get_results(lb_ip, lb_user, lb_pass):
    conn = connect(lb_ip, lb_user, lb_pass)
    if conn is not None:
        print("SSH connection established successfully.")
        stdin, stderr, stdout = conn.exec_command(
            'shell nsconmsg -K /var/nslog/newnslog -g dht_ns_tot_max_limit_exceeds -d current -s disptime=1 | grep dht_ns_tot_max_limit_exceeds'
        )
        print(stdin, stdout, stderr)
        logging.info(f"stdin={stdin}, stdout={stdout}, stderr={stderr}")
        conn.close()
        return stdout.readlines()
    else:
        print("Failed to establish SSH connection.")
        return None
```

I've already added checks in all the funtions to make sure that the SSH connections is established, the command executed on the remote LB and yet, the stdout is empty.

I should receive the list of persistent sessions (the output of the command).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the issued this way, adding the stdout to the variable result, this way it is saved as a variable.

Basically, before I was reading it (so consuming his stream) and then try to read it once again, and of course it was empty.

```
def get_results(lb_ip, lb_user, lb_pass):
    conn = connect(lb_ip, lb_user, lb_pass)
    if conn is not None:
        logging.info("SSH connection established successfully.")
        stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command(
            'shell nsconmsg -K /var/nslog/newnslog -g dht_ns_tot_max_limit_exceeds -d current -s disptime=1 | grep dht_ns_tot_max_limit_exceeds'
        )
        result = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
        logging.info(f"stdout={result}, stderr={stderr.read()}")
        conn.close()
        return result
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to establish SSH connection.")
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `stdin`, `stderr`, and `stdout` variables in the wrong order, it should be `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`

this line: `stdin, stderr, stdout = conn.exec_command(`

just change it like that `stdin, stdout, stderr = conn.exec_command(`

Comment: Tried but still, the output of the script is the following:
 % ./lb-logs.py    
SSH connection established successfully.
[]
Command executed.

But the thing I don't get, the [] isn't this like an empty array? While the output should be a string.

Comment: Yes [] is an empty list in python and get_result() is returning an empty list. I think the command being executed on the remote LB is not returning any output.

Comment: But it shouldn't be a list.. How can I ensure that the command is not being executed? I added this check on the function:

Comment: 'def run_command(command):
    _process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    _output, _error = _process.communicate()
    if _process.returncode == 0:
        print("Command executed.")
        print(_output.decode())
    elif _error is not None:
        print(_error.decode())
        return _output.decode().strip()
    else:
        print("Error while executing the command.")
        print("Exit code:", _process.returncode)
        return None'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do right now. But I believe you are on the wrong track. I suggest you look at this: [Command executed with Paramiko does not produce any output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066517/850848).