# Paramiko is not reading the o/p for the kubectl and helm command. Here is my piece of code

Tags: python, paramiko

Can anyone help me understand how can we read the kubectl and helm command o/p via paramiko

```
    def login(server,username,password):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(server,username=username,password=password)
        output=""   
        cmd= "kubectl get po -A"
        print(cmd)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        print(f'STDOUT:{stdout.readlines().decode("utf8")}')
        time.sleep(5)
        print(stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066517/850848